# Своя авторизация через соцсети?

Tags: yii2, вконтакте, facebook

Какой бест практис, чтобы авторизовывать юзера через соцсети со своими нюансами?

Кейс такой - при регистрации необходимо указать email и телефон.

Соцсеть возвращает email и имя.

Этого для авторизации мало, а терять не охота. И передавать в явном виде, вроде как, не очень профессионально. Как быть?

Реализую на yii2.

Comment: А как на счёт не задавать пароль вовсе, чтобы вход по паролю был невозможен, только через соцсеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после первой авторизации через соц сеть показываем аналог регистрации, только филды email, имя, фото будут уже заполнены. Пользователь дозаполняет форму и самбитит. После этого перекидываете как авторизованного пользователя в личный кабинет.

Comment: при этом я должен сохранить пользователя и валидация при регистрации не сработает((

Comment: нет, сохраните токен ВК в сессию, по нему получите необходимые данные на этапе регистрации. и только после самбита создавайте юзера.

Comment: т.е. записать данные от вк в сессию, а потом к ней обратиться при регистрации?

Comment: @des1roer можно так. после перехода очищаете.

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовая авторизация через соц. сети в Yii2. расширение называется   Yii2-users.
Вот ссылочка на то, как сделать эту авторизацию. [ссылка](http://krivochenko.ru/blog/post/using-yii2-users)

Можно такую запилить авторизацию через соц. сеть.

Надеюсь будет полезна. )